# Show $h:A \rightarrow B$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

I am working through some practice questions, and I am not sure if I am on the right track with this one:

> Let $X = \cup_{n≥1}C_n$, be a space and assume that a map h : A → B
>   is such that each  $h: C_{n} → B$, ∀n ≥ 1 is continuous.
>   If $C_{n}$ ⊆ Int$(C_{n+1})$, f is continuous

I'm not sure if what I have done is too simple - and I am actually missing some important information. But I can't see why this argument would not be complete at the moment.

Let $x$ be an arbitrary element of $X$.

Since $C_{n} \in$ Int$(C_{n+1})$ for $\forall n \ge 1 $ and $X = \cup_{n≥1}C_n$

Then $x \in C_{i}$ for some $i \ge 1 \implies x \in C_i \subseteq$ Int$(C_{i+1}) \subseteq C_{i+1}$.

Since $f:C_{i+1} \rightarrow Y$ is continuous $\implies f $ is continuous at $x$. Since the choice of $x$ was arbitrary $\implies $ f is continuous at every $x$. Hence $f:X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous.

Thanks for any feedback you can give me!

Comment: In a topological space continuity isn't defined pointwise, it's defined in terms of preimages of open sets.  You can argue that convergent sequences in the domain are mapped to convergent sequences in the codomain, but that seems like a tricky approach for this kind of problem.

Comment: @Mnifldz: sequential continuity is not equivalent to continuity for arbitrary topological spaces. And continuity **can** be defined at a point for arbitrary topological spaces. Namely, a map $f: X \to Y$ is continuous at $x \in X$ if for every open neighbothood $V$ of $f(x)$, there exists an open neighborhood $U$ of $x$ such that $f(U) \subset V$. Then $f$ is defined to be continuous iff it is continuous at every $x \in X$. This definition agrees with the usual one (defined in terms of preimages), assuming the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Shalop  - I did begin thinking about this question in terms of subsets - but then I thought - well the question already tells me that $f$ is continuous at each of these $A_i$ - so wouldn't I need to just show that any $x \in X$ is contained in some $A_i$ - and hence $f$ is continuous at every point in it's domain? Is my argument valid?

Comment: The inclusion $A_n\subseteq\text{Int}(A_{n+1})$ is essential. Without that, $f$ could fail to be continuous. For example, let $X=\{x_1,x_2,\dots\}$ be a space with the cofinite topology, and let $A_n=\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$. Then each $f$ is continuous at each $A_n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going from $f\big|_{A_{i+1}}$ continuous to $f$ continuous at $x$ requires some argument. Since $f:A_{i+1} \rightarrow Y$ is continuous, $f:$ Int$(A_{i+1}) \rightarrow Y$ is continuous. Therefore, for any neighborhood $V$ of $f(x)$, there exists a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ open in Int$(A_{i+1})$ such that $f(U)\subset V$. Since Int$(A_{i+1})$ is open in $X$, $U$ is open in $X$ as well. Therefore, $f$ is continuous at $x$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you also need to say that $V$ is open? But also, why does there need to be an argument to go from $f$ continuous on $A_{i+1}$ to $f$ continuous at $x$. This is where my confusion remains. If $f$ is continuous on $A_{i+1}$ then it necessarily must be continuous at every point $x \in A{i+1}$ right?

Comment: Yes, by a neighborhood I mean an open set $V$ containing $x$. The key point here is that $x$ is in the _interior_ of $A_{i+1}$. As a counterexample, take $X = [-1,1]$, $A = [0,1]$ and $f = 1$ on $A$ and $0$ otherwise. Then $f\big|_{A}$ is continuous at each point of $A$ (even $0$), but this does not imply that $f$ is continuous. Indeed, $f$ is discontinuous at $0$.

Comment: Ahh yes, I think I do see your point. But for discussion sake - what if $x$ is not on the interior of $A_{i+1}$? i.e. $ x \in A_{i} \subseteq A_{i+1}$ (rather than on the interior), then if say $A_{i+1}$ is a closed set, and $x$ is on the closure of $A_{i+1}$. But it is given that $f$ is also continuous on $A_{i+2}$ and$A_{i+1} \subseteq A_{i+2}$, then inductively perhaps we have $x$ on the closure of $X$ - wouldn't $f$ still be continuous?

Comment: That is not possible since $x \in A_{i} \subset$ Int$(A_{i+1})$. The second part is given. So if $x \in A_{i}$ it can never be on the boundary of $A_{i+1}$.

Comment: I understand. I meant, if the question was not defined that way, I am just trying to better understand how essential it is that $A_{i} \subseteq Int(A_{i+1})$

Comment: Take the example when $A_{n} = \left\{0\right\} \cup \big(\frac{1}{n},1\big)$. Then $X = [0,1)$. $A_{n} \subset A_{n+1}$ but $A_{n} \not\subset$ Int$(A_{n+1})$. Now take $f(x) = 0$ when $x = 0$, $1$ otherwise. This is continuous on each $A_{n}$ but not on $X$.

Comment: Yes yes, thank you for the examples.